# There are two popovers . At the same time both popovers should not be shown.At a time only one popover should be visible.Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i have a dismissible popover that should hide when clicking on button also? 
Right now only when clicking outside popover will close.But i want it to close when clicking on that button also.

```
<button popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl"  data-toggle="popover"
popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" popover-trigger="focus" class="btn btn-default" popover-placement="bottom" popover-elem>Popover With Template</button>
```

This is the link plnkr.co/edit/ioN7D5OQyRF7KMYw36l0?p=preview

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove

```
popover-trigger="focus"
```

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NOr2qhmPB2iu3qBPJWO7?p=preview) is an updated plunkr.

hope it helps.